# New relic on android import com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelic; not found

Tags: android, newrelic, failed-installation

I want to install 5.12.3 in my Android app with Android Studio. 
I followed step 1 and 2 of the new relic guide line : 
Add New Relic to your build
Set app permissions

Now when I go throw the 'Start the agent' step, I want to do :

> In your default Activity import the NewRelic class. import
>   com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelic;

But I got a 'class not found' error on com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelic

What do I miss ?

Comment: Anyone can help i'm still stuck on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

still stuck?,
I just had the same problem with version 5.17.2, i apparently compiled the New-Relic gradle plugin:

```
"com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.+"
```

in the project's dependencies insted of compiling the agent:

```
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.+'
```

pay close attention to the [New Relic's documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/install-configure/install-android-apps-gradle-android-studio)
or post your project's build.gradle file, i'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you. I was still stuck on it, so I change for another testing / monitoring tool